# move_uploaded_file is not working i'm using php 5.6.25

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

Move_uploaded_file is not working. I've tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
session_start();
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED );
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("v-u-a-p");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  if (move_uploaded_file($temp, "/files/".$name)) {
        print "Received {$_FILES['file']['name']} - its size is {$_FILES['userfile']['size']}";
    } else {
        print "Upload failed!";
}
 $url="http://127.0.0.1/Number1Edward/files/$name";
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUE ('','$name','$url')");
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Number_1_Edward</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?version=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
   $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visable');
  });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
<center><h9 id="Logo">Number_1_Edward</h9></center>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="view.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="upload.php">Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="sidebar-btn">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
</div>
<div id='box'>
 <h1>Videos and Photos:</h1><p>Upload your videos and photos</p>
  <form action="view.php" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!"/><br/>
   <textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Write a discription!(You must right a discription or it wont upload)" type="text"></textarea>
  </form>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  echo"<br/>".$name." has been uploaded";
 }
 ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is uploading all the data to the mysql database but the file is not moving I've tried different commands but nothing seems to be working I've change director many times.There are no errors in the code except for mysql being deprecated and the as been dealt with by using the error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ); command.
I'm using a wamp server and php 5.6.25.
Can you please help me?

Comment: *"Can you please help me and answer quick!"* - Deadline huh? Gee, too bad. We're not on a deadline here; we answer when we can.

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that quick. But the error is right there, easy too see. Be polite next time.

Comment: `and answer quick!` But I can't answer quick :(

Comment: Felippe Duarte wheres the error?

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to use the `__DIR__` to make sure `/files/` is what you think it is.  Like below.

The most likely answer is that it's a permissions issue on the directory that you're trying to write to, so you may want to get a reference to your directory and then check `is_writable()`.

```
$name = __DIR__.'/files/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $name)) {
    print "Received {$_FILES['file']['name']} - its size is {$_FILES['userfile']['size']}";
} else {
    print "Upload failed!";
}
```

Comment: I used the is_writable() and it said the file is writable. Please help.

Comment: @LeonardoStokes Try adding `print_r(error_get_last());` in your else block to get more details on the error.  You could also try dumping `$_FILES['file']['error']`